# Are there any reason to collect and read books in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

There's a whole slew of books in the library. I picked up at least 30 of them I think.  Is there any reason to collect them? There are a bunch of different rarity ratings for the books, some are purple and some are just green. Is there any reason to bother reading them? Some sort of challenge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are in-game achievements for collecting all the books in a set which award a small number of Primogems.

Comment: If they do choose to read, while most seem to be fantasy novels, some of the books do contain lore and history of the world